# How can I select in MySQL only the users from a certain country, based on their IP?

Tags: mysql, select, filter, ip

I am analyzing users from different countries by querying mysql, but I am only interested at the moment in analyzing users from Canada separately from the users from other countries. I have their ip's (they are mobile game players and they play our game) but i don't know how to filter them based on country...Can you help?

Comment: just guessing here, but you could crawl this: http://lite.ip2location.com/canada-ip-address-ranges then put the ranges in a table and then compare what you have with this data.

Comment: looks like it would take years to do that...

Comment: There are API's that will return the location for IPs. It's not fool-proof, but it's fairly accurate. Search for geolocation by IP

Comment: Here is the IP range for Canada
http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/ca.html
Hope this helps.

Comment: Take a look at this [IP JSON](https://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api_json.php). They have an ip to country API.that uses JSON. You could call it using CURL on the server side to get the country based on the IP address.

Comment: @TheoremaLu'Chibritu, on contrary this is rather a really simple page to crawl. use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-ray and that will give you a json with all the data you need in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

To be brief in all cases you will need the IPs of Canada.. But even if you have the database the solution of checking the IP in a specific range or not consume time,

There is too many services (APIs) you can use; the best one so far for me is [maxmind](https://www.maxmind.com/en/home), they have a free and payed version depending on how much details you want.

After choosing the API you want to work with, add a column in your table call it country and update it according to the IP address using the API.. this way you will excute a simple query and filter by countries

In my case as I mentioned I am using maxmind and doing that with perl using [Geo::IP module - you can find more details here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Geo-IP/lib/Geo/IP.pm) .

**simple exemple using Perl :**

```
use 5.014;
use DBI;
use Geo::IP;    
#sudo apt-get install libgeo-ip-perl (then) sudo cpanm Geo::IP

my $table   = 'Gamers';
my $country;

#Connect to you database
my $dbh_s   = DBI->connect(Database(), User(), Pass()) or die($DBI::errstr);

#select the id and IPs of the gamers
my $sth_m   = $dbh_s->prepare("SELECT id, request_ip FROM $table WHERE request_ip IS NOT NULL AND country = '0'"); 
$sth_m->execute();
my $rows    = $sth_m->fetchall_arrayref; die("\n") unless ($rows);

# prepare the query to update the country
my $sth_u   = $dbh_s->prepare("UPDATE $table SET country = ?, updated_time = now() WHERE id = ?");

# here you can use the specific .dat you took from the maxmind
my $gi      = Geo::IP->open("/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD ) or die ("Can't init Geo\n");

# Do the magic (Take every IP and check which coutry)
foreach my $row (@{$rows}) { 

    # I am not filtering IPv6 here so I just send them to US
    if (@$row[2] =~ ':')    { $country = 'US'; } #IPv6
    # The lite free database don't all details sometimes some IPs don't exsit to I just ignore them and mark them by 'WW'
    else                    { $country = $gi->country_code_by_addr(@$row[2]) || 'WW'; }

    $sth_u->execute($country, @$row[0]);
}

# close the connection to the databse
$dbh_s->disconnect;
```

You can put this script in cron and execute it every hour or once a day.. then just `SELECT gamer FROM gamers WHERE country = 'CA';`